# Writing a file in GCP bucket folder fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

I have to write a file to GCP folder.
I have written following code to write but it writes on bucket directly than the folder of bucket.
I am new to GCP, so please help !

I am using following dependencies:

spring-boot-starter-web
spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies
spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies
spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage

What changes I can do ?

I tried below code, but I need to update it to folder.

```
  @GetMapping("/send-data")
    public String sendData() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        try {
                BlobId id = BlobId.of("my-bucket", "demofile1.json");
                BlobInfo info = BlobInfo.newBuilder(id).build();
                byte[] arr = fileData.getBytes();
                storage.create(info, arr);
            }
       }
```

Above code works well, but I have created a folder as "test" in the bucket and now I want to write a file in that "test" folder rather than in bucket.

Comment: Folders do not exist in Cloud Storage. The namespace if flat. The solution is to include the folder name in the name of the object.

Comment: more details here https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the file to a specific folder in your GCP bucket, you just need to update the BlobId object the following code example mods should be fixing your problem.

```
    try {
            String folderPath = "folder/subfolder/";
            String fileName = "demofile1.json";
            BlobId id = BlobId.of("my-bucket", folderPath + fileName);
            BlobInfo info = BlobInfo.newBuilder(id).build();
            byte[] arr = fileData.getBytes();
            storage.create(info, arr);
        }
```